# Android BottomNavigationView slide animation on fragment change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, material-design, android-bottomnavigationview

I am trying to achieve this BottomNavigationView behavior in Android:
[image]

(Example is from iOS)

My current app layout is:

```
|- ConstraintLayout
  |- MaterialToolbar (gets hidden for some fragments)
  |- FragmentContainerView (here, the fragments for screens are changing)
  |- BottomNavigationView (gets hidden for some fragments)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I know that my current layout will probably make this impossible, but is there any other common way to do this?

I found that I can use ViewPager with two pages and switch to second page if I want the fullpage and switch back if I do not want it, but that seems sketchy to me.